# How do I assign 1 ISP to each VM on a server

Tags: networking, ip, isp, virtual-machines

Do I need to have X different network cards ? If so, How can I possibly connect them all ? Not enough slots.
Let'say I have 13 different ISP providers, and 12 virtual machines and a W7 Host.
I want to assign each ISP to each vp and 1 ISP to the host machine. The IP can't get mixed up.
A router ? many network cars ? 
Please enlighten me.
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The simple answer is VLANs.  Your ISP source connections go into an static access port in your switch each on its own VLAN(you switch must support VLANs).  The switch port connecting to your Host system , and the NIC and software in the host will need to support "Trunking" which will allow all the ISP connections to be tagged (separated) and carried on the same wire to your host.  You'll then configure your hypervisor software with some virtual networks - one for each ISP(VLAN).

Hope this is helpful.  VLAN's aren't black magic or really very difficult.

Good Luck - Jeff

Answer (score 1):

Possible solution is as follows:

1. Get a switch with VLAN support
2. Get a virtulization platform that supports vLAN's too, e.g Vmware ESX
3. Get a router or multiple routers
       with VLAN support.

Depending on the VLAN type chosen you might reach different levels of flexibility. Generally 802.1Q is preferred over port based. Here is related [VMWare document](http://www.vmware.com/vmtn/resources/412).